# Deleting information from the command prompt

Tags: python, for-loop

I have a code that uses for loop to extracts light magnitude (in this case refered to as `phot_bp_rp_excess_factor`) (Bp), from a certain table.

My code:

```
coord =SkyCoord(table["ra"], table["dec"], frame="icrs", unit="deg")

for i in coord:
    r= Gaia.query_object_async(coordinate=i, width = u.Quantity(0.0005, u.deg), height=u.Quantity(0.0005, u.deg))
    bp=[r["phot_bp_rp_excess_factor"]]
    print (bp[-1])
```

Output/ Command prompt display:

```
INFO: Query finished. [astroquery.utils.tap.core]
phot_bp_rp_excess_factor
------------------------
11.4

INFO: Query finished. [astroquery.utils.tap.core]
phot_bp_rp_excess_factor
------------------------
14.4
...
```

However, I only need the numbers, in this case, 11.4 and 14.4. I don't want it to say `" INFO: Query finished. [astroquery.utils.tap.core]" phot_bp_rp_excess_factor` every time it does a loop because I am trying to create a list/array of my light magnitude numbers. Does anyone know how to do this?

Edit:  I don't know if this information is relevant in solving the problem but here I am using Astropy library and Skycoord comes from that library.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My best bet based on the [library's source](https://github.com/astropy/astroquery/blob/98e9537ef1e86a85e775b42c0522ed7c87aa6d52/astroquery/utils/tap/core.py#L453) is that it's just a `logging` logger.

You can turn the verbosity down for that particular logger with e.g.

```
import logging
logger = logging.getLogger("astroquery")
logger.setLevel(logging.INFO)
```

but all in all it might be better to just never mind the logging messages and separate your data gathering/printing stages:

```
coord = SkyCoord(table["ra"], table["dec"], frame="icrs", unit="deg")

data = []

for i in coord:
    r = Gaia.query_object_async(
        coordinate=i,
        width=u.Quantity(0.0005, u.deg),
        height=u.Quantity(0.0005, u.deg),
    )
    bp = r["phot_bp_rp_excess_factor"]
    data.append((i, bp))

for i, bp in data:
    print(i, bp)  # Or whichever formatting you'd like
```

Also, logging data usually goes to the standard error stream, not the standard output stream, so if you're running your program from the command line, you can just redirect to a file and only get your `print()` output:

```
python myscript.py > output.txt
```

Comment: I tried the  separating the "gathering/printing stages", and in the  "priting stage", one of the out put I get is `phot_bp_rp_excess_factor--- 11.469192`. So I am still getting the `phot_bp_rp_excess_factor` text instead of just the number `11.469192`. I thought maybe I should create a panda dataframe to store just the number. When I did that using `df = pd.DataFrame({'BpRp' : bp})` followed by `df.to_csv('cerca.csv', index=False, encoding='utf-8')` It only saved the last result from my loop. Do you know why this is the case? or other possible solutions to this?

Comment: You would need to figure out what the type of `bp` is and how to get just the data out of it. Try `print(type(bp))`...

Answer (score 0):

if you want to hide the INFO message, you can try:

```
import logging
logger = logging.getLogger()
logger.setLevel(logging.CRITICAL)
```